# Google Maps Intent with marker & user position

Tags: android, google-maps

Can you launch from an APK a Google Maps intent that includes both a marker with a specific location and the user position? I've been trying to but haven't been able as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/storing-and-retrieving-locations-in-sqlite-from-google-maps-android-api-v2/

try this site man i guess it will help.helped me though.

Comment: This is for showing the position whithin a Fragment, I want to launch an intent to the Google Maps app with a predefined marker and the user position

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + latitude +","+ longitude +"&daddr=" + userLatitude + "," + userLongitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good workaround but it isn't showing the user position in real time but a static position based on my own detection of the user location.

Comment: Why dont you use google map in your application? Do you have to open the google map application?

Comment: I do use Google Maps, but my app does not navigate or offer any of the many other features Google Maps provides, so I implemented a button that allows direct access to Google Maps and I would like for it to show both my POI and the user location.